# Source Server support on VMs with VMWare Lab Manager and TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, authentication, vmware, symbol-server, tfs-2005

My company is interested in better integrating our investment in VMWare with our TFS deployment. Currently the company is running TFS2005 SP1, VS2010, and we have a sizeable SAN that we would like to use in environment reproduction similar to what is offered in TFS2010 Lab Management.

Of the features offered by TFS2005, we are currently leveraging only TF Version Control--work items and build automation are handled by separate systems. However, we would like to use the TFS-integrated Symbol/Source server in order to accurately debug the different versions of our product, and that's where we're running into difficulty.

The VMs deployed in VMWare are not joined to the corporate domain, and this means that we run into difficulty when attemping to grab source code information via Source Server and the "tf.exe view" command.

- If devenv is run on the VM, it can't authenticate a domain account, and tf.exe view fails when grabbing source info.
- If devenv is run on the developer desktop and debugging is done with remote debugger, the vm's local user account fails to access the share exposed by Symbol Server and can't load symbols to begin with, much less retrieve source.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Did the answer below end up helping you get this problem solved?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes - You can still do this.  If you are using Windows 7 (and I believe Windows Vista) you can always add the domain credentials to the "Credentials Manager" in the Control Panel.  This will help it authenticate for the TFS URL whenever it needs to talk to TFS.

BTW, I have a blog post discussing the Symbol Server and Source Server features of TFS 2010 available here:  http://bit.ly/SymbolServerTFS